# tkinter user non closeable window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a program where i have removed the main window close options and providing a exit button to the user to close the program.

After pressing i need to do some processing in the background which would be time consuming, i don't want user to close the program while that is going on accidentally. Is there a way to remove all buttons from the messagebox which is presented ?

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from tkinter import messagebox


def on_closing():
    pass

def exit():
    messagebox.showinfo("Wait", "Please wait for background process to complete")
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(width,height))

exitButton = tk.Button(root,text="Exit",width=15,command=exit)
exitButton.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=6,pady=6)

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

In the Background : There are some files generated on user's machine and i would like to archive them using python library. The files can go maybe sometime at 1GB so i think it would take more amount of time, if the laptop on which it is run is having very less computing power. And this would be the case for my base hence i want them just to wait until that popup is closed. This i can define in user manual.

Comment: You need at least one button, it is part of the specification of a message box.

Comment: I am okay if we can do without inbuilt message box also, is there any other way ?

Comment: Maybe create a flag? That checks if the work is going on and then closes the window if task is done.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to remove the buttons, or is this an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? There are ways in tkinter to run code when the user presses the [x] to close the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I have edited the question to say what i will be doing in background. So, i dont want any user to close it casually while sitting idle in front of that.

Comment: Is it important that the window is visible while this process is happening? Why not just delete the window, and then continue to do the processing? It's possible to have code run after the window has been destroyed.

Comment: Yes, because they need to share the zip file after closing application. If zipping is done in background user will not know when it is complete and then share the file. Ofcourse i think from backgroound process we can again launch a popup to show completion but i would not like to do that. I am okay with the current solution provided so i am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what work you want to do, but for this example I'm doing a work of printing something and then sleeping and then printing it. So this takes about 20 seconds. And in those 20 seconds you wont be able to exit the GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import threading

def on_closing():
    if started == False: #if work is not going on, then quit
        root.destroy()
    else: # else show the message.
        messagebox.showinfo("Wait", "Please wait for background process to complete")

def work():
    global started
    started = True #mentioning that the work started

    print('Hey')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('There')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Whats Up')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Cool?')
    time.sleep(5)

    started = False #mentioning that the work stopped

started = False #initially work is not started
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(width,height))

exitButton = tk.Button(root,text="Exit",width=15,command=on_closing)
exitButton.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=6,pady=6)

Button = tk.Button(root,text="Work",width=15,command=threading.Thread(target=work).start)
Button.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=6,pady=6)

# root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

Here, `started` acts like a flag. You have to set it to `True` before starting your work and set it to `False` after it ends.

You can ignore the fact that I created a new button and used `threading`, it was just to simulate to you an example of work done. Threading helps the GUI to not freeze. Though I'm not sure if this will work with `root.overrideredirect(True)`, but I think you can get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you , i checked and yes this can work. But i don't have much experience in better UI design, but isn't this a bad UI workflow ? The user can close the infopopup and then again go and press exit button and then we show again user the infopopup ? User will think the application is having bug and then close from task manager ? I have edited my question to say what i will do in the background.

Comment: @user34974 I actually dont think that is true, because if the work is going on, its the mistake of the user by trying to close the app right? But you can show them a another popup saying the work is done or you can disable the exit button. Neither do I know much about UI